# react-native firebase retrieve user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to make a call to firebase to retrieve an user by the Id which is stored in my context.

```
 const obj = firebase.database().ref("/users/" + userContext.state.userId).once('value')
```

[image]

But when i console.log(obj) it returns a Promise instead of an object

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

Edit 1 :
I have tried this

```
const obj = database.ref("/users/" + userContext.state.user).once('value').then(snapshot => console.log('User data:', snapshot.val()))
```

But it prints : User data: null

Comment: The function you tried doesn't have userId , you are passing "userContext.state.user" while you need to pass "userContext.state.userI'd"

Comment: you are right that was a misspell, now the snapshot.val returns the object. How do i save the object from snapshot?

Comment: Good to know that your code is working , great .

Comment: Could you post your answer, storing the object in a variable so i can accept your answer

Comment: added the code , hope will work according to your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code

```
var user;

firebase.database().ref("/users/" + userContext.state.userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
user= snapshot.val();
});
```

Hope will work according to your need

in case you need to use the value in state

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      User: '',
      YourOtherData :'',
      YourOtherData2 :'',
    };
  }

getUserData(){
firebase.database().ref("/users/" + userContext.state.userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
     const userData = snapshot.val();
     this.setState({ User: userData });
    });
}
```

}

Comment: This is the closest correct answer, but it if i console log user it says undefined

Comment: where are you using console.log ,    below user= snapshot.val(); or outside the function

Comment: i wanted to use user outside the function so i changed .once to .on

Comment: @GherghinaAndrei Hi I think you should  use state for It as you need to use that value in anywhere of your application you need to call getUserData() for this , also you do same for anyother data retriving from firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const obj = firebase.database().ref("/users/" + userContext.state.userId).once('value', function (snapshot))
```

If you console.log(snapshot.val()) this is what you should get:

```
Object {
  "avatar": "test avatar",
  "email": "fffsfss@yahoo.com",
  "name": "Enter name",
  "username": "Enter username",
}
```

What do you want to do with the userID?

Comment: Hello i've tried something like that : const obj = database.ref("/users/" + userContext.state.user).once('value').then(snapshot => console.log('User data:', snapshot.val()))  but it returns null

Comment: I am trying to make a profile page, i have the userId in the context i just need to get the user details so i can show them

Comment: For some reason it expects }